# Memory leak in a delphi with TList<string>

Tags: delphi, generics, memory-leaks

Good day,

I have class

```
TMn2Adapter = class(TPersistent)  
  private
    FGrid: TStringGridPointer;
    FList: TList<string>;
    // ...

  public

  constructor Create(AGrid: TStringGridPointer);
  destructor Destroy();
end;

constructor TMn2Adapter.Create(AGrid: TStringGridPointer);
begin
  FGrid := AGrid;
  FList := TList<string>.Create();
end;

destructor TMn2Adapter.Destroy;
begin
  Dispose(FGrid);

  FList.Free;
  FList := nil;

  inherited;
end;
```

and another one

```
TMn2Worker = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FMn2Adapter: TMn2Adapter;
  public
    constructor Create(AGrid: TStringGridPointer);
    destructor Destroy();
end;

constructor TMn2Worker.Create(AGrid: TStringGridPointer);
begin
  FMn2Adapter := TMn2Adapter.Create(AGrid);
end;


destructor TMn2Worker.Destroy;
begin

  SysUtils.FreeAndNil(FMn2Adapter);

  inherited;
end;

procedure TMn2Adapter.Parse;
begin
  FList.Clear();
  for I := 1 to FLenght do FList.Add((FGrid)^.Cells[2, I]);
end;
```

Creating TMn2Worker in a form  `mn2: TMn2Worker`, doing some action and `onFormClose` I free this one `mn2.Free`. And I get report from Eurekalog about memory leak (see attached image). It seems to me that something strange happen in a parsing TStringGrid`s cell to the TList.

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your destructor is never called because you did not include the `override` directive. Declare destructors like this:

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

Some of the rest of your code looks dubious, although we can't see enough to be say anything for sure. Unfortunately you removed most of the relevant code. In one of the variants you call `FreeAndNil` on a reference that you already set to `nil`. That clearly is somewhat pointless. And in the other you `Dispose` a pointer that you didn't allocate which smells odd. Finally, it's not obvious why you would have a pointer to a reference type. That usually indicates a misunderstanding of reference type variable assignment.

Comment: Should a destructor be generally overridden in subclasses?

Comment: @David : Good catch!  Sometimes the obvious is all too easy to miss.

Comment: @Alberto Always, because otherwise it won't get called when you call `Free`.

Comment: Ah ok it will call the father's destructor then